# Iphone App Swift main screen works. Aborts on the second page

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

I am extremely new to Swift. Before I go on to my issue, I would like to thank everyone that takes time out of their day to help solve issues people are having.

I have been experimenting with swift by making a pool calculator app. I have the basic function to figure out how much chlorine someone needs to put in the pool etc...

The main page is just a filler but then when I click "Pool Calculator" , it aborts and gives me the error " SignalBRT"

The code (sloppy as it is) works and i have been experimenting with just a simple addition app that works fine.

But for this one, the code works fine and it gives me an issue. Since it is the "SignalBRT" error, it is such a broad meaning to what the error would be and I do not know what is causing it. I feel like it could be the scrolling view that i added but before i added any functions, it scrolled up and down fine so my assumption would be the "CalculateChlorine" part of the code

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   // @IBOutlet var Number1: UILabel!
    //@IBOutlet var Number2: UILabel!
    //@IBOutlet var Field1: UITextField!
   // @IBOutlet var Field2: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var VolOfpool: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var CurrentR: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var DesiredR: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var labelResult: UILabel!
    var DefaultChlorineWeight: Float = 2.0// in oz
    var CurrentReading: Float = 1.0
    var DesiredReading: Float = 2.0

    @IBAction func CalculateChlorine(sender: AnyObject) {
      //let a = (Field1.text! as NSString).floatValue
      //let b = (Field2.text! as NSString).floatValue
      //let sum = a + b

      //  labelResult.text = "\(sum)"

        let Volume = (VolOfpool.text! as NSString).floatValue
        let CurrentReading = (CurrentR.text! as NSString).floatValue
        let DesiredReading = (DesiredR.text! as NSString).floatValue

       let resultForChlorine = (DefaultChlorineWeight * (Volume/10000) * ((DesiredReading - CurrentReading) / 1))
        labelResult.text = "\(resultForChlorine)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

here is my error:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  // it says error SignalBRT here
```

kind of hard to see without a picture but the first screen of the app has a button called " Pool Calculator" where it sends it to another screen where the user would input the values . The second screen aborts and gives me the error.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Make sure your outlets are properly connected, and that you don't have redundant variables in storyboard/xib on second screen. Please add the code or way how you start second screen

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your storyboard. Make sure that all your connections are hooked up properly, make sure that your action buttons are connected properly as well. Do you have anything in the `viewDidLoad()` method on your second screen?